# netfilter-persistent and iptables malfunction

Tags: iptables, firewall

Desiring to use iptables on ubuntu 18.04, I removed the ufw and installed iptables-persistent netfilter-persistent.
Edited the /etc/iptables/rules.v4 and tried to start the netfilter-persistent service.
It's working, but the last exit status is not 0, probably something's wrong when stopping the service.

iptables -nL output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.129        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

status of the service:

```
root@my-server:/etc/iptables# systemctl status netfilter-persistent
● netfilter-persistent.service - netfilter persistent configuration
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-05-26 12:39:17 UTC; 19min ago
  Process: 4402 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4408 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4408 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)


May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver netfilter-persistent[4408]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver netfilter-persistent[4408]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver systemd[1]: Started netfilter persistent configuration.
```

journalctl -e -u netfilter-persistent.service

```
May 26 12:39:01 my-webserver systemd[1]: Started netfilter persistent configuration.
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver systemd[1]: Stopping netfilter persistent configuration...
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver netfilter-persistent[4402]: Automatic flush disabled; use '/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent flush'
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver systemd[1]: Stopped netfilter persistent configuration.
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver netfilter-persistent[4408]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver netfilter-persistent[4408]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
May 26 12:39:17 my-webserver systemd[1]: Started netfilter persistent configuration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is from the script which gets called by the systemctl command.
Service:

```
/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service
```

The service file is calling the */usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent* script with "*stop*" argument.

snip:

```
stop)
    if [ ${FLUSH_ON_STOP} -gt 0 ]; then
        run_plugins flush
    else
        echo "Automatic flush disabled; use '${0} flush'"
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
```

So, it eneters in the *else* condition and exits with status of *1* echoing "Automatic flush disabled; use /usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent flush".
What I don't know, if this will cause some issue at the firewall level.